How to politely ask Pakistani team during call to slow down speech, enunciate clearly, and get headset mics?
I'm in the Midwest USA, my accent is not rural, and I'm dealing with a Pakistani team over calls that talks fast, have thick accents, and whose mics are all just the built-in computer ones (they sound far away), not headsets. Also, they enunciate in a very tight-lipped way, so a lot of words sounds mumbled or smeared together. None of my local teammates have these issues.
I've asked multiple times for them to speak slower, louder, more clearly, and get closer to the mic or get a headset, but it seems to offend them and they don't change much, or quickly go back to the fast-talking. They can also start talking like I'm stupid as if it's not just a legibility issue. Often I'm left to ask them to repeat themselves or just let it go and hope I can figure it out later. My hearing isn't great but most teams I've worked with don't speak in ways that result in sounding like gibberish a lot of the time.
I've worked with other teams from India, China, and the Philippines, and usually it's OK enough or they do a better job adjusting. I haven't worked with Pakistanis before so I don't know how much of this is just cultural. To me understandability is a global concern and so any culture or team should work to make adjustments for understandability, as I've done for others. It's not hard for me to get a headset or talk slower or enunciate more or just explain things more succinctly.
They're not a cheap team and are very experienced, so I've asked them to get headsets for our next meeting to at least alleviate the far-away "echo room" issue.
What I'm looking for here is the preferred ways in Pakistani culture to ask for improvements in team meeting communicatuon like this so I'm not coming off as rude or stupid.

To be clear, when you say, "None of my local teammates have these issues", do you mean your local teammates understand this particular foreign team acceptably, or something else?

I have periodically had to remind friends from the Indian subcontinent that their dialect of English is sometimes hard for us Americans to understand, and that even when it sounds perfectly clear to them, it may still be different enough from hours that we are struggling. On the other hand, practice makes better; I can understand that dialect better than I used to since I've had more practice. Adaptation is probably needed by both sides.

Why do you insist on asking politely? They're not being very polite to you!

@A.I.Breveleri: Hanlon's razor. Never assume malice when ignorance is an adequate explanation. Start by assuming they simply don't realize there's a problem, since after all they understand each other's English perfectly, and ask politely, since they are more likely to accept your request that way. If that doesn't do the job, rudeness is still not called for; politely ask management if there's anything they can do. That is, assuming you want to retain this job.

@keshlam - OP: "I've asked multiple times for them to speak slower, louder, more clearly, and get closer to the mic..." "They also start talking like I'm stupid as if it's not just a legibility issue." I'm not seeing the courtesy here.

It can be hard for people who think they are speaking your native language to believe that you are having trouble understanding it. It can also be difficult for folks in a conference room to understand that their speakerphone is not picking them up well, and that speakerphone's are pretty awful and handling the situation when multiple people are speaking at once, unless they have experience with being on the other end of the line. I still think this could be handled politely, via education, rather than making a fight out of it.

I witnessed a situation in which two people with good English talked: one native, one not. The non-native answered a question with number "firty" (exactly in the middle between thirty and forty). Obviously, the other did not understand and asked twice for clarification, and the answer was copy-paste "firty". What the native English speaker did next was to thank for the information, and to suggest to continue the discussion privately by mail - solution which was gladly accepted.
That is exactly what I suggest to you: keep the spoken meetings for generic stuff. For what matters, use written communication. In case of problems, you even have proof of the cause of the problem. The e-mails from them can even be used as an "incentive" for them to have additional training of English.

Additionally, involve your manager. Have him join one meeting (or a few), and he can the escalate the problem to the Pakistani management somehow.


... or just let it go and hope I can figure it out later

No NOT do that! If anything bad will happen, you will be 100% percent. Just send e-mails to clarify anything that is left unclear. The mail can be as simple as:

Please remind me ... (whatever information you need)


Additionally, start using a task tracker, and ask them to write whatever information is needed in there. It reduces the number of meetings greatly, and work will be more organized. If you already have a task tracker, use it more - and use meetings less.

Create a meeting minutes document during the meeting. Share the MM after the meeting. Ask them to clarify anything which is not clear or not correct. Make sure that the MM contains ALL your questions.

Send them questions by mail. If they answer by conference, ask them explicitly to also answer in written by mail - replying to your email.
Keep your manager in the loop. report all transgressions. Allow him to have first hand experience with your remote team, so he understands how to escalate the issue.

Switching to written communication is great if the accent/pronunciation is the only issue.  However, it doesn't help much if you also find the choice of words/phrasing/idiom or just written communication generally unclear.  (In that case, IM is likely to be better than email, as you can at least ask for clarification in real time.)

@gidds: that is exactly OP's problem, clarification in real time does NOT work in his case. In other situations, clarification is faster with voice. However, even then, sending an e-mail with the decision (like a MM) is a good practice.

"Firty" "What?" "Firty" "What?" "Firty" <-- Not getting anywhere. "Firty" "Fourty as in four-zero?" "No, firty as in three-zero" <-- Problem solved.

@Stef: you are right, but that is already not very politically correct - suggesting in public that someone's pronunciation (especially a manager's) is not good enough. It is not only what can be done, but what should be done too. (Un)fortunately, we are not on Vulcan - Live long and prosper! :) We are all driven by emotions, some more than others. I would not mind for being corrected nicely. But I received downright obscene reactions for even the most innocent remarks. Just saying.

@virolino I don't see anything "not very politically correct" about asking clarification for a critical piece of data over the phone. It's notoriously harder to understand people over the phone than face-to-face, and most of communication is redundant (if you misheard one word in a sentence, your subconscious will usually fix it), but a price is not redundant, so spelling the number out clearly is only logical.

@Stef: As I wrote, there were already 2 or 3 requests for clarification. More debate on the issue would have been deeply wrong. IMO

But my point was mainly that people tend to repeat exactly the same thing when someone says "What?" "Sorry?" or "I didn't catch that", and repeating exactly the same thing typically does not remove the ambiguity, regardless of what caused the ambiguity (could even be an actually ambiguous sentence and not a pronunciation issue). So it helps to ask for explicit clarification instead, for instance by spelling out the number's digits.

I'm not suggesting to keep asking the speaker more than three times for clarification. I'm suggesting to make a distinction between "asking the speaker for clarification" and "asking the speaker to repeat themselves". Most listener tend to ask the speaker to repeat themselves, which doesn't help, instead of directly asking for clarification.

@virolino, would it be right to assume it was more like "fir'ee", using a so-called glottal stop? It's not just the "th" altered, but the "t" sound too.

@Steve: If I remember correctly, it would be wrong to assume that :) However, either "ty" or " 'y", the confusion is mostly the same.

@virolino trust me us non native speakers know very well that we make mistakes. We're usually happy when somebody dumbs it down when there is a misunderstanding. Nothing about is this political incorrect. On the contrary it is much appreciated. You start talking normal and then when you start having problems just switch to more basic language.


They're not a cheap team and are very experienced, so I've asked them to get headsets for our next meeting to at least alleviate the far-away "echo room" issue.

If you have managerial authority, then directing them to get and wear headsets with quality microphones, and allowing it as a company expense, would be the most effective solution by far.
The only circumstances in which people are paid enough not to allow the expense, is when they probably have an expense account already and it would be considered a trifle claim, so don't get into an implied mentality that people are already being paid enough to cope.
This avoids completely the issue of politeness.
If the problem isn't already resolved with better sound quality, then of course you can move to tackling more behavioural issues.
It's also worth pointing out as well, the price or technical experience of a foreign team has no necessary connection to their foreign language skills.
Because of former British control of India (which included Pakistan), there are widespread informal English language skills there, but terminology and accents often diverge to the point that it is more akin to some of the extreme dialects found on the British mainland (especially where there is some history of non-English language in the area), which can be unintelligible even to other native speakers.
